# How find parallel diagonal reverse at other diagonal in matrix 2D in C++

Tags: c++, matrix, reverse, diagonal

I have a problem to manage a two-dimensional matrix nxn in C++. My problem is create a function that control if exists any diagonal, parallel line at the principal diagonal, that is reverse to other. I controlled the two index, necessary for the rows and columns, if are different and maybe I could help me with support arrays, which reverse the elements. Perhaps it's not a good idea with a huge matrix(such as 8x8, 14 arrays) so, I am asking your help.

Thanks

[image: an example with matrix 4x4]

This is my code:

```
bool funct(short **M, int rows, int columns){
bool found = false;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < colums; j++){

        if(i != j){
            //control the reverse array
        }
    }
  }
}
```

ps: my primary problem is general algorithm(nxn).

Comment: Is the matrix always quadratic? Btw, 8x8 is not even near huge.

Comment: Yes, I am not still practice with matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by control. Do you just want to identify these elements in a single iteration through the matrix or do you let say want to put all those diognals in there respective arrays?

Comment: I want only identify at least two diagonal which one is reverse to other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a quadratic matrix, every diagonal has exactly one other diagonal with the same length (except the principal diagonal). So you just need to check this one:

```
for(int diagonal = 1; diagonal < cols - 1; ++diagonal)
{
    //inspect the diagonal that starts at (0, diagonal)
    //the other diagonal starts at (diagonal, 0)
    int diagonalLength = cols - diagonal;

    //Assume that this diagonal has a reverse counterpart
    bool diagonalHasReverse = true;

    //Now check if it really has
    for(int i = 0; i < diagonalLength; ++i)
    {
        if(M[i][diagonal + i] != 
           M[diagonal + diagonalLength - 1 - i][diagonalLength - 1 - i])
        {
            diagonalHasReverse = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //do whatever you want with diagonalHasReverse
}
```

The outer loop does not process the very last (one-element) diagonal. If you want to include that, you have to modify the loop as follows:

```
for(int diagonal = 1; diagonal < cols; ++diagonal)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be diagonal < cols -1 ?

Comment: @Ahmed.J Why? The last diagonal is a single element and could also be considered to have a reverse counter-part.

Comment: Well yes if thats what one want I was saying because of the two higlighted diagonals in the image and not the last element

Comment: You're right. Apparently, this is what the requirements say. Editing...

Comment: If i want include the last element (in my example is 3) ?

Comment: @Andrew Yes, in this case you need to adapt the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you so much.